# Installation problem with Ubuntu from USB

Tags: usb, system-installation

I followed the instructions, but now I want to install it but I get the following message

```
The creation of swap space in partition failed #6 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sdb) failed
```

[image]

I have partitioned my HDD into the main one for mac and for Ubuntu I gave 40gb. Is there a step I'm missing?

1. /dev/sda1
   fat32 ----- EFI ---- -----------------200.00MiB ---- 18.56MiB ---- 181.44MiB ---- boot
2. /dev/sda2
   hfs+ ------- Macintosh HD---- 426.75GiB -------    90.94GiB  ---   335.81GiB
3. unallocated
   unallocated         -------------------     128.00MiB
4. /dev/sda3 
   hfs+        ------- Ubuntu  -------------     38.57GiB  --------    149.21MiB ---   38.42GiB
5. unallocated 
   unallocated       ------------------        128.02MiB

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include a screenshot of your partitions. Preferably, a screenshot after partitioning your drives before selecting **Install Now**. This will be very helpful.

Comment: In mac OS or from the USB live ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu Live Disk

Comment: I tried to make a table, it didn't save properly. It won't let me insert an image since I dont have enough point of some sort.

Comment: [upload it](http://postimage.org/) online and post back

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/5om9a8lqb/

Comment: Does the image work?

Comment: Yes it does. The hfs+ ubuntu is it ok to format it?

Comment: Yes of course. I have partitioned the one in the macbook and it was said online that the part that was partioned would be automaticaly used for the installation of ubuntu. To be honest, I have already tried with someones instructions to partition the Ubuntu part into two different parts : ext4 and swap-linux, but at the end, it would not work, because the efit program could not sync partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. delete the `sda3` hfs+ ubuntu partition. This will combine the two unallocated spaces to give **38.8GB** of unallocated space. Create the first partition for swap. When creating the swap partition use as Swap Area. Then the second for **/**. Select the appropriate bootloader i.e. `dev/sda (465.76GB)`

Comment: All of this is done in the live USB disk? Is the partition swap created from the 38.8GB? I do not understand what you mean by selecting the bootloader.

Comment: Yes. The saw partition is created from the 38.8GB. For the bootloader, disregard that. Leave is as default. Just create the sawp and root and you should be fine.

Comment: Just to be clear, I delete the Ubuntu partition. I create the swap partition, how much memory do I allocate? Then I create the root partition, how much memory do I allocate and which file system (ext4) ? Once all this is done, I start up the installation?